# Expected Lifetime (flexsurv)

Tags: r, statistics, survival-analysis, weibull

I'm using `flexsurv` to compute expected lifetime for a given population by fitting a weibull curve to the data.

```
library(survival)
library(flexsurv)
data <- read.csv(file)
survival_col = data[["survival"]]
duration_col = data[["duration"]]
w <- flexsurvreg(Surv(duration_col,survival_col) ~ 1,data=data, dist="weibull")
```

Given `w`, how can I compute the area under the curve, so to speak, to get the expected lifetime?

Comment: Try reading this post on [how to make a great r reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), and you may get more helpful answers

Comment: You might also take some time going through the vignette included in the package if you haven't done this already. It is well-written and fairly extensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the expected life time by doing:

```
lifetimes <- predict(w, type = "response")
```

See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexsurv/flexsurv.pdf) the documentation for the predict method for `flexsurvreg`